# Identify the sender-iframe from message when sandboxed

Tags: javascript, iframe, sandbox

Fictional situation for simplification:

- I have a `grandparent` page containing one `parent` iframe displaying the "parent page".
- This "parent page" contains two children iframes `childA` and `childB`.
- All the iframes are `sandbox="allow-scripts"` for security reasons.

`parent` sends and receive messages from/to `grandparent`, `childA` and `childB`.

When `parent` receives a message, I need to be able to identify the sender, but I can't find the right approach, as the `origin` of the `event` is `null`:

```js
function onReceive(message) {
    // origin is null when the message comes from a sandboxed frame.
    console.log(message.origin);
}
```

Do you know a clean way to know who does the message come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it was simpler than I expected.
I actually can compare the `message.source` property with the `contentWindow` of the child `iframes`, or `window.parent` for the grand parent.